# android service http architecture

Tags: android, http, service, architecture

I creating application that communicate with web server by http.
User need to able receive notification from web server even when application is down .
To do so I realize that I need to use service to run in background .

My quastions is about application architecture :

Do I move all http implemantation to service , and communicate with it from main UI ?

Do I use service only when app is not active to store/show notifications from web server , 
 and run http client on separate thread , and when app down turn service on ?

Should it be service in separate process ?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited with link about client side implementation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using GCM (Google Coud Messaging) from google it's the best way to handle push notifications from server side
Check this link for more info https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

EDIT

Here is a link about implementing in client side 
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: GCM on web server ok , what about architecture on user side

Comment: Check the link it explains the how to for both sides

Comment: @user3004288 edited with link bout client side implementation

Comment: Is that possible to use pc application windows that use GCM to communicate with mobile device?